# Exclude a folder pattern from sublime sidebar

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to exclude the .vagrant folder from my Sublime Text 3 sidebar but I can't seem to get the configuration right.

**First I tried**

```
"folders":
[
   {
     "path": "path-to-project",
      "folder_exclude_patterns": [".vagrant"],
      "file_exclude_patterns": [".*"]
   }
],
```

**Then, I tried excluding the "path"**

```
"folders":
[
   {
      "folder_exclude_patterns": [".vagrant"],
      "file_exclude_patterns": [".*"]
   }
],
```

**And finally I tried (although I knew this wouldn't work)**

```
"file_exclude_patterns":
[
    "*.vagrant"
],
```

The answer posted in this [support forum post](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5739) didn't work for me. This is all in my *User Preferences* file. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured it out. I needed to rename `folder` to `folder_exclude_patterns` with this syntax.

```
"folder_exclude_patterns":
[
   ".vagrant",
   ".git"
],
```

For more on this check out this [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=17792) support forum post.